# How to determine orientation of the separating hyperplane in LIBLINEAR?

Tags: libsvm

For binary classification problems the output of LIBLINEAR is a single hyperplane. How to determine which side of it corresponds to which class?

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out the learned feature weights correspond to the class which occured first in the training data set. Not very convenient.

Comment: And [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f430)'s the reference for this information.

Comment: There is FAQ for LibSVM, not LIBLINEAR.

Comment: Ups, sorry, my bad, but I expect Liblinear to work in a similar way.